# Python code to get files from FTP server and copy into a Specific folder on my computer

Tags: python

i need help with a python code to Get all .CSV files in a FTP server and copy them into a specific folder C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Test . example FTP server xx.com, username xx1, password xx2.

```py
import os
from ftplib import FTP

ftp = FTP("xx.com")
ftp.login('xx1', 'xx2')
ftp.login()
ftp.retrlines("LIST")

ftp.cwd("users")
ftp.cwd("_ADPPGC") # or ftp.cwd("folderOne/subFolder")

listing = []
ftp.retrlines("LIST", listing.append)
words = listing[0].split(None, 8)
filename = words[-1].lstrip()

# download the file
local_filename = os.path.join(r"C:\Users\sam\Desktop\Test", filename)
lf = open(local_filename, "wb")
ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + filename, lf.write, 8*1024)
lf.close()
```

Comment: You haven't posted the code you need help with, nor explained just what help you need with it.

Comment: You'll get more help if you demonstrate some effort to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Lengthy code in comments is hard to read.  Edit the question and add the code there.

Comment: Just added the code in the question. Sorry

Comment: So ... what specific problems are you having with this code?  Does it produce errors?  Does it do something different than what you wanted?  Does it do anything at all?

Comment: It says [Erno 13]  permission denied. 'C:\Users\sam\Desktop\Test'